# Can I pass a deligate to a Xunit Theory

Tags: xunit.net

I'm interested in reusing a test theory on a number of classes, specifically a number of constructors that need to the same tests.  I initially had the idea of using a delegate to carry out this functionality.

However, I think I'm probably trying to reinvent the wheel and although C# has some functional capability I think I'm attempting an improper method.  Is there a supported method for this kind of thing using something more correct than InlineData.

InlineData seems to be for inject the input so I might test many examples of a given test. But can I supply several variables to several methods and get testing ^x not *x

```csharp
[Theory]
[InlineData(input => new ConcreteConstructor(input)) ]
public void Constructor_Should_Not_Throw_Expection (Action<string>)
{
  constructor("SomeString");            
}
```

N.B I think I should be using `Func` in this case as an object is returned.  Anyhow I suspect it's completely the wrong approach so it's not the main consideration.

Comment: You can pass a `Func` as a test arg using the `MemberData` mechanism (you can't make Func's with attributes so its never going to work with `InlineData`

Comment: Thanks @RubenBartelink I'll have a go with MemberData

Comment: I think you can't use Func here, because different constructors will return different types. So, it can be possible only if all your types have the same base class. Then at least you can cast to that base class and check some base stuff.

Comment: Agree @yevheniy-tymchishin.  There us no need to return anything anyway as were looking for exceptions not results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```cs
public static IEnumerable<object[]> TestData()
{
  Action<string> a1 = input => new ConcreteConstructor(input);
  yield return new object[] { a1 };
  Action<string> a2 = input => new AnotherConstructor(input);
  yield return new object[] { a2 };
}

[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(TestData))]
public void Constructor_Should_Not_Throw_Expection(Action<string> constructor)
{
  constructor("SomeString");
}
```

Comment: This is certainly the answer to of the title.  I had a bit of a discussion point with this => Should I reuse code like this. I think in may cases I would use the abstract base class but there will be cases when passing a delegate is the right approach.  Polymorphism vs Composition.  One reason I like the inheritance approach is that I get nice names for my tests and it's arguably easier to read.

Comment: I think here is no correct answer - you have to decide: delegates or inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [Yevheniy Tymchishin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7310982/yevheniy-tymchishin) for his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64685201/9179925) and I would like to add additional way, just in case if someone want to add delagate without declaring a new object outside the yield return.

```
static IEnumerable<object[]> Data
{
    get 
    {
        //Yevheniy's approach
        Action<string> a1 = input => Construct(input);
        yield return new object[] { a1 };

        //new approach with hidden parameter
        yield return new object[] {new Action<string> (Construct)};
        
        //same but with exposed parameter syntax
        yield return new object[] {new Action<string> ((input) => Construct(input))};
    }
}
```

All three of them do exactly same thing, just in a different syntax, same logic would apply to any other delegate type(func or whatever)

Answer (score 0):

One solution with inheritance of a common abstract class:

```csharp
abstract public class CommonTest_ConstructorShould
{   
        public abstract void Constructor(string input);

        [Fact]
        public void Constructor_Should_Not_Throw_Expection()
        {
            Constructor(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Constructor_Should_Throw_Exception()
        {
            Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => Constructor("/PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP"));
        }
    }

    public class LunarCalendarClient_ConstructorShould : CommonTest_ConstructorShould
    {   
        override public void Constructor(string input){
            new ConcreteClass(input);
        }
    }
```